# Execute batch file. How to call .bat file, visual studio command prompt and change directory in opened command prompt window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file

```
@echo off
echo copy masterDB file from one directory to another one
copy "C:\dir\dbfile"  "C:\dir1\dbfile" 
cd c:\lvsdir
call lvsrun.bat
timeout /t 180
start %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
MSTest /testcontainer: C:\testdir\test.dll
```

I want to do via a batch file to copy a db file from one directory to another one(which executes correct), then should start lvsrun.bat file, which should start lvs server,
and then to open visual studio command prompt in a new window, change directory in opened command prompt to test directory and run test file. Problem occurs when i call lvsrun.bat, and it stucks there. New vs command prompt can't be opened. And having problem with changing directory in opened vs command prompt and run test file. Code above doesn't really work

Answer (score 5):

You've asked two questions here.  You should split them up and ask them as two separate SO questions.

Q1. Why is my batch file never getting past `call lvsrun.bat`?

A1. Because `call` will not return until the batch file it is calling has exited.  If you want to launch lvsrun.bat and continue execution immediately, use `start`.

```
copy "C:\dir\dbfile" "C:\dir1\dbfile"
cd c:\lvsdir
start "" "%comspec%" /k lvsrun.bat
```

---

Q2. Why doesn't the new command window I launch run my test file?

A2. Your batch file will only control *its* command window.  If you launch another command window, that one is on its own, you can't "send" commands to it.  But you could instead run the test in the *current* window rather than launching another:

```
:: Use "call" here to run vcvarsall.bat to set up the environment in this process
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
MSTest /testcontainer: C:\testdir\test.dll
```

Or you could make a second batch file just for running the test.  For example, let's call it `runtest.bat`, and give it those exact same lines:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
MSTest /testcontainer: C:\testdir\test.dll
```

which would then get called from your original batch file either synchronously:

```
call runtest.bat
```

or asynchronously:

```
start "" "%comspec%" /c runtest.bat
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I already checked answer to the 1st question. When you change directory and then use start, it changes directory where copied the db file. And tries to start batch file from home directory in a new window. Tried different ways, but still no result