# How to run Coded UI test file from Visual Studio command prompt using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, coded-ui-tests

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
start %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat""
MSTest /testcontainer:C:\testdir\test.dll
```

Code shown above runs vs command prompt and changes directory to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"` where MSTest.exe is. But last line doesn't run in vs command prompt window, opens new window and tries to run in a new opened window. Can anyone help how to run ui test file in opened vs command prompt using batch file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute batch file. How to call .bat file, visual studio command prompt and change directory in opened command prompt window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252202/execute-batch-file-how-to-call-bat-file-visual-studio-command-prompt-and-chan)

Comment: unfortunately an answer there didn't solve my problem regarding this question.

Comment: `start %comspec% /k` starts another window, so you should not be surprised. Try `call "c:\....vcvarsall.bat"` instead.

Comment: @Stephan: I used to try call, but then I'm not able to change directory to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" ` after call to start `MSTest`

Comment: `set testpath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\"
%testpath%MSTest /testcontainer:C:\testdir\bin\Debug\test.dll ` solved problem

Answer (score 1):

I run my Coded UI tests with the following batch script:

```
@echo off
:: Running tests without VS Enterprise is possible if you install the Test Agent package: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx

set test_runner="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
set test_dlls="C:\Location\Compiled\Tests\Project.CodedUI.Test.dll"

:: If tests is set then only these comma separate test cases are run
:: set tests="Test1,Test2"
set tests=""

if %tests% == "" (
     %test_runner% %test_dlls% > CodedUITestResults.txt
) else (
     %test_runner% %test_dlls% /tests:%tests%
)
pause
```

The visual studio number should be replaced per different version

- VS2015: 14.0
- VS2013: 12.0
- Etc